# PDO connection string works on my computer but not on online

Tags: class, pdo, localhost

I did a straight connection to PDO. this works on my computer but not online when I upload. Why is that? Is it compulsory that create a class for it.

```
$conn=new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass));
```

when I go online, it gives me "Fatal error: Class 'PDO' not found in..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether the php-pdo Extension is both installed and active.  You can either use `phpinfo` or `get_loaded_extensions` for this.  In case it is not active, check whether it is installed and active it in your php.ini; otherwise install it.